# ASP.NET Core 5.0 Linq Outer Join

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-5.0

- I've got `Movements` and `Equipment`...

  - but not all `Movements` have `Equipment`.
- For example, a "*Back Squat*" requires a Barbell, Plates, etc.. but a *"Pushup"* doesn't require any equipment.
- So, I've got a bridge table linking the `Movements` that do have `Equipment`.
- I need an `OUTER JOIN` so I can access all of the `Movements` even if they do not have any `Equipment`.
- ...I hope that makes sense.
- My code below only results in `Movements` that have matching `Equipment` records in the bridge table.

```cs
Movements = (
    from mvmt   in applicationDbContext.Movements
    join mvmteq in applicationDbContext.MovementEquips on mvmt  .MvmtId  equals mvmteq.MvmtId
    join equip  in applicationDbContext.Equipment      on mvmteq.EquipId equals equip .EquipId
    orderby mvmt.MvmtId
    select new Movement
    {
        MvmtId = mvmt.MvmtId,
        MvmtDescr = mvmt.MvmtDescr
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Why arne't you using `Include` with navigation properties?

Comment: Agree, well-designed models with navprops give that functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        var query =  
        from mvmt in applicationDbContext.Movements
        join mvmteq in applicationDbContext.MovementEquips on mvmt.MvmtId  
        equals mvmteq.MvmtId
        join equip  in applicationDbContext.Equipment on mvmteq.EquipId equals 
        equip.EquipId into g
        from mvmteq in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where mvmt.MvmtId != null
        select new
        {     
          MvmtId = mvmt.MvmtId,
          MvmtDescr = mvmt.MvmtDescr
         }).ToList();
```

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Movements = (
            from mvmt in applicationDbContext.Movements
            join mvmteq in applicationDbContext.MovementEquips on mvmt.MvmtId equals mvmteq.MvmtId into join_1
            from mvmteq in join_1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join equip in applicationDbContext.Equipment on mvmteq.EquipId equals equip.EquipId into join_2
            from equip in join_2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new GetMovementRequest
            {
                MvmtId = mvmt.MvmtId,
                MvmtDescr = mvmt.MvmtDescr,
                MvmtMetrics = mvmt.MvmtMetrics,
                MvmtStandard = mvmt.MvmtStandard,
                EquipId = equip.EquipId,
                EquipDescr = equip.EquipDescr
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- You really don't want an `OUTER JOIN` query.
- If you want to load all `Movement` and all `Equipment` data then all you need is this:

```cs
static async Task<( IReadOnlyList<Movement> allMovements, IReadOnlyList<Equipment> allEquipment )> LoadEverythingAsync( this ApplicationDbContext db, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
{
    IReadOnlyList<Movement>  allMovements;
    IReadOnlyList<Equipment> allEquipment;
    {
        List<Movement>  mov = await db.Movements.ToListAsync( cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        List<Equipment> eqp = await db.Equipment.ToListAsync( cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);

        await db.MovementEquips.LoadAsync( cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);

        allMovements = mov;
        allEquipment = eqp;
    }

    return ( allMovements, allEquipment );
}
```

The code above "works" because the Entity Framework `DbContext` performs *magic* whenever you load data into the `DbContext` (from both `ToListAsync` and `LoadAsync`) such that all attached and loaded entities will have their reference and navigation properties' setters invoked.